# Virtual inheritance - why this output

Tags: c++

Take a look at the code below. Why the output from `static_cast<D2&>(m).f()` and `cout << static_cast<B&>(m).f()` is `33`, not `21`?

```
struct B {
    virtual int f() {return 1;}
};
struct D1 : virtual public B {
    virtual int f(){return 2;}
};
struct D2 :  virtual public B{};
struct M : public D1, public D2 {
    virtual int f() {return 3;}
};

int main(){
    M m;
    cout << static_cast<D2&>(m).f();
    cout << static_cast<B&>(m).f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be `21`? The whole point of virtual functions is that function calls are dispatched to the dynamic type of the object, not its static type.

Comment: Do you understand that you don't need virtual *inheritance* here, only virtual *functions*? Virtual inheritance in this case is no different from normal one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's the entire point of virtual dispatch: The target of the dispatch is determined by the *dynamic type of the most-derived object* that contains the statically nominated object of the call expression.

If you *don't* want virtual dispatch, you can bypass it by qualifying the function call:

```
m.B::f();
m.D1::f();
m.D2::f();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object is an instance of `M`, and casting to base reference types doesn't change that.  The whole point of virtual functions is that when you call a function on a base pointer or reference, it goes to the derived implementation.